# csc (cosecant) periodic equation and unexpected results

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, trigonometry

I can plot 1 (co-secant) every second over 2 seconds and it looks fine (**the top plot**).  But when I plot the frequency of 100 csc (co-secant) signals **I would expect / want 100 co-secant signals that are just repeating the same signal much like plotting y=.8*sin(100*t) would do** but that doesn't occur what am I doing wrong?  See code and plot below.

```
clear, clc
fs=8000
len_of_sig=2; %length of signal in seconds
t=linspace(0,2*pi*len_of_sig,fs*len_of_sig);
y_a=0.01*csc(1*t);
y_a(y_a >=1) = 1; %used to limit amplitude
y_a(y_a <=-1) = -1;

y_b=0.01*csc(100*t);
y_b(y_b >=1) = 1;
y_b(y_b <=-1) = -1;

t2=t./(2*pi); %converts time in radians to seconds
subplot(2,1,1);plot(t2(1:end),y_a(1:end));
subplot(2,1,2);plot(t2(1:end),y_b(1:end));
```

Ps: I'm using octave 4.0 which is like matlab
[image: plot]

Comment: What you've found is an example of [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions). As pointed out by gnovice, increasing the sampling rate will fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing in the second subplot is the result of reduced sampling per cycle. You are increasing the frequency of `y_b` relative to `y_a` by a factor of 100, but still using the same vector of time points `t`, meaning you have 1/100<sup>th</sup> the number of points per cycle in `y_b`. These fewer points per cycle fall at slightly different offsets to the discontinuities, giving you the pattern above.

You can fix this by using an upsampled time vector for `y_b`:

```
t_up = linspace(0, 2*pi*len_of_sig, 100*fs*len_of_sig);
y_b = 0.01*csc(100*t_up);
y_b(y_b >= 1) = 1;
y_b(y_b <= -1) = -1;
subplot(2, 1, 2); plot(t_up./(2*pi), y_b);
```

[image]